# Automatically fetch uid and gid in a command

Tags: terminal, mount, cifs

I'm using the below command to mount CIFS share, but I want to fetch the UID and GID automatically in the same command so that I don't have to enter it manually every time I `mount` on different machines. Any advice how?

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD},uid=<user>,gid=<group> \
   //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `id` command:

```
$ id
uid=1000(muru) gid=1000(muru) groups=1000(muru),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo)...
```

Just the UID:

```
$ id -u
1000
```

Just the GID:

```
$ id -g
1000
```

So, using command substitution:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o "username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD},uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)" \
   //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu
```

Comment: Could you please advise how I can write the same command in `/etc/fstab` so that it's mounted automatically?

Comment: @Tak that won't be possible in fstab, since you cannot use commands or variables in it. Writing a script to be run at startup might be better.

Comment: Can you advise how this script can be written and called?

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I've posted a question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457921/mount-using-fstab-instead-of-terminal if you can check please? as the provided answer didn't mention how to autotomatically fetch the uid and gid and you said it can be done using a script but I don't know how, so if you could please help?