# Mount using fstab instead of terminal

Tags: terminal, mount, fstab, cifs

I am mounting my shared drive using terminal in my Ubuntu machine like this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o "username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD},uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)" //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu
```

I wonder how I can permanently mount it using `/etc/fstab` keeping in mind that I'm automatically fetching the uid and gid as shown above?

Comment: what are you means of:automatically fetching the uid and gid and what would you of it?

Answer (score 1):

A syntax similar to this will do the job to create an `fstab` entry to what you are asking:

```
//server-address/folder    /mount/path/on/ubuntu        cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,uid=1001,gid=1001 0 0
```

I advise using the `/root/.smbcredentials` file in order to hide the authentication credentials.

You may also run the command mount after you run the command on the question to see the approximate syntax.

See related:  [CIFS randomly losing connection to Windows share](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367884/cifs-randomly-losing-connection-to-windows-share/367885)

Comment: But how I can get the uid and gid automatically instead of hardcoding it? as I'm using many machines and they have different gids and uids

Comment: You should have unified gids and uids, either through a central server or doing the effort manually. Or using it in a database + scripting or MySQL; however I am afraid that detailing the steps of it is out of scope here.